# Cargar Automaticamente un archivo INPUT FILE y leerlo de una vez

Tags: php, html, html5, xml, archivo

Estoy intentando cargar un archivo xml a un input file, y cunado ingrese se ejecute un onchange para que se lea el archivo y lo asigne los textos. es decir, le doy a examinar -> busco selecciono el archivo -> cuando le de abrir y cargar en el input me realice la lectura del mismo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Importador</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<!--onchange="if(!this.value.length)return false; muestrame();"  -->

<form name="f1" id="f1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

Archivo XML<input type="file" name="archivoxml" accept="text/xml" id="id_archivo" onchange="if(!this.value.length)return false; muestrame();" >
<input type="hidden" name="prueba" id="prueba">

<table width="506" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cliente:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cliente" id="id_cliente" ></td>
      <td>Nombre contacto</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="contacto" id="id_contacto" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>direccion de despacho:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="direccion" id="id_direccion" ></td>
      <td>comuna</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="comuna" id="id_comuna" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ciudad:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ciudad" id="id_ciudad"></td>
      <td>comision</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="comision" id="id_comision"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>condicion de pago:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="condicionpago" id="id_condicionpago"></td>
      <td>orden de compra</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ordencompra" id="id_ordencompra"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fecha de entrega</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fechaentrega" id="id_fechaentrega"></td>
      <td>vendedor</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="vendedor" id="id_vendedor"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fecha VB:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fechavb" id="id_fechavb"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<?php
                                 
$cotizacion = simplexml_load_file("data.xml"); <<<------ AQUI deberia entrar el archivo.


/*DATOS DEL CLIENTE*/

$varcli = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->cliente);
$varcon = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->contacto);
$vardir = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->direccion);
$varcom = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->comuna);
$varciu = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->ciudad);
$varcomi = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->comision);
$varcomp = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->condicionpago);
$varordc = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->ordencompra);
$varfeen = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->fechaentrega);
$varvend = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->vendedor);
$varfevb = utf8_decode($cotizacion->datos_cliente->fechavb);

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No funciona asi, lo que puedes hacer es una llamada ajax a tu controller de php que haga ese proceso y te retorne los datos.

Answer (score 1):

```
var reader = new FileReader();

$.(document).ready(function(){

    $('#id_input').on('change', function(e){`
        var obj = e.target.files[0];
        reader.onload = (function(f){
            $.('#contenido_xml').html(f.target.result);
        });
        reader.readAsText(obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. en español @Jose Alvarez. Gracias por tu aporte, pero es necesario que expliques de qué forma y cómo el código soluciona el problema planteado. Si brindas más información tu respuesta será considerada de mayor calidad y más usuarios podrán entenderla y beneficiarse de tu conocimiento,